# XSL producing HTML can not insert HTML fragments from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

What I want to achieve:

1 XSL file produces an HTML output based on XSLT.
Parts of the output HTML is stored in XML. So you need to read that part from an XML and insert it (merge) with the other content that XSL directly produces.

Example Code **XSL**:

```
<div>
  <h1>This is a title</h1>
  <p>And this is the content coming from XML:<br/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="/*/xhtml:myelement" />
  </p>
</div>
```

And the **XML** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <z:article xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <ns0:myelement>&lt;p>here is some text with a special character &amp;#776; and &amp;#187; but actually any valid html can be stored like this in XML.&lt;/p>&lt;br/>  
    &lt;h2>an H2 title in the XML&lt;/h2>
    &lt;p>and again some text&lt;/p> 
  </ns0:myelement>
</z:article>
```

What I get as **output** is the HTML itself (as text), so it is still escaped and therefore not interpreted as HTML:

## This is a title

And this is the content coming from XML:
<p>here is some text with a special character &#776; and &#187; but actually any valid html can be stored like this in XML.</p>
<h2>an H2 title in the XML</h2>
<p>and again some text</p>

**So my question is:** HOW can I write the XSL code so that the text in the XML is copied as actual HTML and not as TEXT ?

Comment: In your XML for `myelement`, are you escaping the HTML or are you providing the HTML as HTML? If the former, then it will be copied over escaped.

Comment: @Bob : the HTML in the XML is escaped, as shown in my question. If it would NOT be escaped, it would work but I cannot change that as it comes from a source I can't influence

Comment: Then, what you have **isn't** HTML. There isn't a function in XSLT which will "de-escape" source that is escaped. You will likely have to use a pre-processing program that removes the escaping so that you can insert it into your output.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Hi Bob, sounds reasonable what you say. However, **[this example](http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rLY/3)** shows that it should also work with escaped HTML code... Maybe you see something that is different to my example.

Comment: I see what you are demonstrating. The key features of the solution are `value-of` and `disable-output-escaping` as @michael.hor257k describes.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I understand, but the `disable-output-escaping` has no effect in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="ns0:myelement" />
```

try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ns0:myelement" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Comment: @basZero "does not work" is not a good description of a problem. It works for me (see: http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rLY), but then I am using a well-formed XML as the input (unlike what you posted).

Comment: if the html would be well-formed it would work, I tested that too. But the HTML is escaped in the XML

Comment: @basZero I am afraid you are completely missing the point here: the **XML** code you have posted is not well-formed, because the `z:` prefix is not bound to a namespace. Therefore I have removed it. I have no idea if the **HTML** is well formed or not, and it doesn't matter; the purpose here, I believe, was to return the HTML code unescaped - and that's exactly the result produced here. Have you looked at the link I have provided in my previous comment?

Comment: @michel I looked at your code, need to compare as your example really works... I would love to see my example work too... Have to analyze the differences

Comment: I now changed your example so that it pretty much reflects our implementation ([Link](http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rLY/3)). Still: it works, but not in my own project.